# Python/Dash: How to filter values categories on Pivot Tables while plotting?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

A sample of my dataset looks like this:

```
date    enrolled
6/29/2018   1
6/29/2018   1
6/29/2018   
6/29/2018   1
6/29/2018   1
6/29/2018   1
6/29/2018   1
6/20/2018   1
6/20/2018   1
6/22/2018   1
6/19/2018   1
6/19/2018   1
6/27/2018   1
6/28/2018   1
6/28/2018   1
6/28/2018   
6/28/2018   1
6/28/2018   1
```

I made pivot table and plotted scatter from it through this code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('demo.csv', encoding="latin-1", infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates=['date'], skipinitialspace=True)

pv = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['date'], values=['enrolled'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # Converts date to datetime dtype

df["enrolled"]=pd.to_numeric(df['enrolled'], errors='coerce').fillna(0) # Converts float to numeric adding zero to empty cells

dfb.enrolled.round(0).astype(np.int64) # Converts Float to int

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=pv.index, y=pv[('enrolled')], name='Enrolled')

trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv.values == 0, name='No Criteria')

trace3 = go.Scatter(x=pv.index, y=pv.values == 2, name='Rejected')
```

***PROBLEM***

I am unable to do trace 2 and trace 3:

Trace 1: I am able to plot if enrolled equals to 1

Trace 2: I want to plot if enrolled equals to empty cells

Trace 3: I want to plot if enrolled equals to 2

Initial dtype of date was object and converted to datetime
Initial dtype of enrolled was float and converted to int and then to str (object).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what it its you're asking? This is hard to even edit into something I can understand. I don't want to misinterpret what you are asking.

Comment: @ScottSkiles, I want to represent graphically with scatter plot the number of empty values in the cells per day. So, I dont know how to proceding dealing with empty cells while using pivot_table of pandas.Thanks